# Using $ sudo bundle exec ... raises 'bundle: command not found' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, sudo, rbenv

I have installed rbenv on an Ubuntu sever. I can cd into my application directory and run `$ bundle` without issue, however I need to run `$ sudo bundle exec ...` and this gets me an error:

> bundle: command not found

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's because you installed rbenv AND your gems as user, not as root.

how you fix it? not using sudo, why you need anyways, is something very specific?

Comment: Why do you need to run it with `sudo`? (The reason it's not working is that when you run under sudo, you are running as root which has a different environment.)

Comment: @rodrigo.dk Yes. Unfortunately I'm using Foreman and exporting Upstart files and it needs sudo privileges.

Comment: @shioyama So without duplicating the rvm install to root, this isn't possible? Could I give the current user sudo privileges?

Comment: @Pedr see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan Carley's [rbenv-sudo](https://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo) looks like it will do what you want:

> rbenv-sudo is a plugin for rbenv that allows you to run rbenv-provided Rubies and Gems from within a sudo session.

A more detailed explanation of how it works is provided in this article: [Sudo Rbenv Me a Sandwich](http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/03/06/sudo-rbenv-me-a-sandwich/)

Comment: You're correct. That would be the way to go, but unfortunately I'm running this command from a Capistrano deploy, and this causes the deploy to hang asking for a password, but without the usual prompt.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure, but maybe this would work for you:

```
sudo -i -u $USER bundle exec...
```

or

```
sudo -i -u username_with_correct_env bundle exec...
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you get the error has been addressed already. But I was able to get around it by saying:

```
sudo /full/path/to/bundle exec ...
```

In my case, I'm using rbenv, so I had to:

```
sudo /home/renier/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec ...
```

That worked. To get sudo to not ask for a password, you would need to configure your `/etc/sudoers` file for this. See https://serverfault.com/a/160587.

Answer (score 2):

To do this without using rbenv or rvm, do this:

`sudo -E bundle exec ...`

> ```
>    -E          The -E (preserve environment) option will override the env_reset option in sudoers(5).  It is only available when
>                either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in sudoers(5).  sudo will return an error
>                if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
> ```