# bundle install - command not found - running as root

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems

I am using Amazon EC2 instance and when I run `bundle install` as ec2-user, it works fine but when I try the same as root user, it gives error.

`bash: bundle: command not found`

There is bundler gem exist when I run `gem list` for both users. I have installed ruby-devel rubygems ruby-libs as root user. Can anyone please help me understand this issue? I have searched and read for hours.

echo $PATH of both users are as below.

root:
`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin`

ec2-user:
`/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using $ sudo bundle exec ... raises 'bundle: command not found' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647745/using-sudo-bundle-exec-raises-bundle-command-not-found-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` to secure_path in `/etc/sudoers`

```
sudo visudo
```

Then change this line:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Changed this to

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Explanation:

Gems were installed at /usr/local path and without adding this in secure_path, root user cannot run scripts from there. You can check your gems path by running `gem env` in shell.

I also had another issue. I installed gems as ec2-user using bundle and default rubygems path in Amazon Linux installed them only for ec2-user, something I did not like so I installed ruby and rubygems from source which has path to installed them at central location under /usr/local. I know it is not recommended by many but I like it this way. By the way, I tried to find a way to change rubygems path but I could not.

Comment: Hi, any explanation for this?

Comment: Hi Tommy, I added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo -i -u $USER bundle install`

where `$USER` is the correct username so : `sudo -i -u root bundle install`

If this does not work, consider giving a try to [the rbenv-sudo plugin](https://github.com/dcarley/rbenv-sudo).

Comment: Still the same error `bash: bundle: command not found`. I tried as root user and also as ec2-user.