# sudo bundle causes `could not find bundler` error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I have `bundle exec` works fine, but when I'm trying to execute `sudo bundle exec`, I have `Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0)` error.

This is the full error message.

```
smcho@macho appname> sudo bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
/Users/smcho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 11 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/smcho/.gem/ruby/2.2.0:/Users/smcho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/smcho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/smcho/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/smcho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/smcho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/smcho/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I found many questions/answers related to this issue, but nothing seems to work.

- [Using $ sudo bundle exec ... raises 'bundle: command not found' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647745/using-sudo-bundle-exec-raises-bundle-command-not-found-error)

  - I tried the answers from this post, but nothing works. Anyway, my error message is not `bundle: command not found`.
- [Why is sudo: bundle command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456998/why-is-sudo-bundle-command-not-found)

  - I have same results from both `$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sh` and `$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `bundle` command, you need to install `bundler` first:

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Then you will be able to use `bundle` command:

```
sudo bundle exec . . .
```

Checkout [bundler official page](http://bundler.io/) for more information.

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam: I updated my post, as I forgot to explicitly mention that the issue is only with sudo.

Comment: Maybe you didn't install bundler as sudo?

Comment: What happens if you install bundler using `sudo` like this: `sudo gem install bundler`?